# zone-evergreen.js error after upgrading angular from 8 to 9

Tags: javascript, angular

I just upgraded angular 8 to 9 and now I am seeing this error in the console:
[image]

It doesn't appear to be causing any issues, but I really prefer having a clean console. Any ideas on where I can look, or how I can eliminate this?

**package-lock.json**
[image]

**package.json**

[image]

Comment: What is the zone.js version? Can you check the .lock file for the version details?

Comment: Check your zone.js version respects this version compatibility table: https://www.npmpeer.dev/packages/@angular/core/compatibility (should be either `~0.10.2` or `~0.10.3`, depending on `@angular/core` version).

Comment: @KanishkAnand I just added a screenshot. It's set to 0.10.3 in the lock file. But in package.json its set to 0.10.2

Comment: @ChrisKooken If angular core is < 9.1.1 I think zone 0.10.2 is recommended. For > 9.1.1 zone's 0.10.3 should be fine. You should probably try and put the exact version in package.json instead of using `~0.10.2`

Comment: @KanishkAnand I installed version 0.10.3 but the error still shows

Comment: I figured it out, it was a Chrome Extension "Angular Profiler Devtools" that was causing the issue.